# Having multiple scripts within one php

Tags: php

I  am  trying to find out how to have multiple scripts within one php file, and run
Certain scripts only when a certain link is clicked on (or some other input from a user). For example, the default output Of profile.php is the user's "wall", but when they click "info" on the profile.php page (the page reloads because I'm not using JavaScript and that's okay for now) the main content area would now display the user's info (as printed by a script within the original profile.php file) how is this done?

Comment: Do you want to clone Facebook?

Comment: Have you read about 'include' or 'require' ?

Comment: @gustav it seems he's looking for a condition

Answer (score 3):

That's fairly easy. Using only one php file, you can have many "actions" that displays some stuff depending on what you need. Take a look of this simple source code (save it as "file.php" or use the name you like and edit the "a" tags. I've included the name of the file as some browsers do not work correctly when the link starts with "?".

```
<h3>Sections</h3>
<a href="file.php?action=home">Home</a>
<a href="file.php?action=wall">Wall</a>
<a href="file.php?action=profile">profile</a>
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['action']) {
  $action = "home";
}
else {
  $action = $_GET['action'];
}

switch($action) {
  case 'wall':
    display_wall();
    break;
  case 'profile':
    display_profile();
    break;
  case 'home':
  default:
    display_home();
    break;
}

function display_wall() {
  echo("Wall");
  // Do something
}

function display_profile() {
  echo("Profile");
  // Do something
}

function display_home() {
  echo("Home");
  // Do something
}
```

Tweak that code a bit to fill your needs.

Comment: Could you explain what is happening here: if (!isset($_GET['action']) {
  $action = "home";
}
else {
  $action = $_GET['action'];
}

Comment: To prevent errors, I check if the user is passing a parameter to the "action" variable. if you access ..../file.php the "$_GET['action']" will not be set, so, it defaults to the "home" action. If the user accesses ..../file.php?action=wall the "$_GET['action']" variable will contain 'wall', and thus, the $action variable will be set accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You should learn something about [predefined variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php) `$_GET`, `$_POST` and for the later use, `$_COOKIE`

```
<?php
if ($_GET['clicked'] == "info") {
    //show user's info
}
else{
    //show another info
}
?>
<a href="?clicked=info">Click to see info</a>
```

Comment: The above code will help you to run certain script on specific action on the same page

Answer (score 1):

You can use require_once("navigation.php")

On every top of the page where navigation.php includes your Home,Wall,Profile links...

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP-developer. But I think the most basic way is using querystring and includes...

So your front-facing file is profile.php, but you also have info.php and wall.php which you include dynamically based on the query-string...